# How to structure recusrive categories in Angular, perhaps using ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm a beginner Angular guy and I need some help structuring an application. The part I'm having difficulty with is a categorization system.

The Category model has the fields: title, slug, parent category, image, type. Categories can be of simple type (title only, no image) or full (title and image). Other category types should be possible to create in the future - for example, category with lengthy description and no children. Categories can be automatically expanded (a simple category with subcategories has its children expanded by default) or not (a full category by default is not expanded).

Visually, it should look like the following: a category has a title, and inside it the images and titles of subcategories, like apps look on your phone's home screen:

[image]
https://s3.amazonaws.com/ish-archive/2016/bjjcollective/20160215.bjjc-uiux.png

When you click one of those "app"-looking things, that subcategory's title gets added to the hierarchy of titles (so the categorization acts as a tree), and the subsubcategories are shown, as app-looking things.

When you click on the title of a parent directory, the children tree gets replaced with the expanded view of that category's subcategories.

Additionally, each category should have a url associated with it, for example: /categories/houses/kitchen/silverware ( /categories/:slug_0/:slug_1 or /categories/*slugs ? ) should be the page where silverware category is expanded, and its subcategories are shown. The slugs are not unique! So you can have a path like /categories/camping/kitchen/silverware as well, which would be different from "houses" silverware.

The backend API can have any shape that's usable by the frontend. /api/categories.json, /api/categories/houses.json?depth=2, /api/category/houses.json - it's completely flexible.

So I am looking into ui-router and directives to make this happen but I don't see how I should structure my code. To tie views to the url I have to use ui-router, not directives, right? Is recursive views a thing in Angular? And, if each category has a sub-view, how do I restrict rendering of subcategories to only the one relevant subview? I have a pretty solid idea how to do it in jQuery, but how do you do it in Angular?

Comment: Suggest you study some tutorials on ui-router. Views can be nested and url can have various params in it that are used to filter data or determine view templates. Beyond that this question is un-answerable

Comment: The question is answerable, but maybe I need to expand it into several separate questions.

Comment: Well not answerable within the guidelines of this site would be better way to put it. You are basically asking for a theoretical breakdown of router features and how to integrate them